# Strange Label/Tooltip behavior, nvd3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, linechart

I may be missing something simple, but my nvd3 line chart graph isn't displaying quite right. All of the x axis ticks are spaced out evenly, except for the first two which are sandwiched together:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

The code I'm using to construct the chart is:

```
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                  .showLegend(true)
                  .showYAxis(true)
                  .showXAxis(true);

  chart.xAxis
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y')(new Date(d))
      })
      .rotateLabels(-45);

  chart.yAxis
      .axisLabel('Number of Visits')
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

  var myData = timeseriesData;      

  // render the chart
  d3.select('#timeseries-chart svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .call(chart)

  return chart;
```

Any ideas on how to spread the first two ticks apart, and why they are so close together?

Comment: Yes, the data would be very helpful. Putting it in a Plunker or JSFiddle would be even better.

Comment: The problem is probably related to how your data is formatted. Please post your data.

Comment: Try setting showMaxMin to false: chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(false);. I agree a Plunker or JSFiddle would be really helpful.

Comment: Aha, indeed it was the data. I was pulling in an extra day of information. Thanks for the tip everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an extra day of data. More carefully filtering it did the trick.